# CORS origin issue from web application

Tags: reactjs, cors, keycloak

I am having a bit of a problem here.
I have Keycloak where I have enabled CORS (value '*') and I can call endpoint:

> /auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token

from Postman, where I get response with access token and other stuff, but when I try to call that endpoint from my React application, I get CORS error:

[image]

I don't get why, since I have set '*' value for Web Origins in that client.
Is this a Keycloak bug, or am I missing something trivial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this issue by creating Web API project in .NET Core (this could be done in any other technology). I have setted CORS policy in my project to allow any domains and then I make direct calls to Keycloak endpoints from .NET Core project. Besides fixing this issue (since .NET Core Web API project is not a browser application, this is working like a charm), this adds another security layer to the Keycloak by hidding client information that is only accessible from .NET Core application. Information like client_id and client_secret are not visible from browser application and no one can do any damage to my clients in Keycloak.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the address 'http://localhost:3000/*' added on the `Valid Redirect URIs` keycloak config?

Comment: I have placed it, saved, refreshed my web app and still CORS error.